# Cannot resolve symbol 'scp' in IntelliJ IDEA 11 Ant build script

Tags: ant, intellij-idea, scp

I'm running IntelliJ IDEA 11 on Ubuntu Linux.  I have an existing project that I've imported into IDEA with a build script that performs a bunch of `<scp>` tasks.  IntelliJ is underlining all of my `<scp>` tasks and giving me the message of `cannot resolve symbol` even though I have `jsch-0.1.42.jar` both on my Global Classpath in IntelliJ as well as on the Additional Classpath for this specific Ant file.

[image: Cannot Resolve Symbol]
[image: Ant Additional Classpath]

What do I need to do so that IntelliJ will recognize `<scp>` as a valid task?

Comment: I was wondering if and how you might have resolved this issue? I'm having this same problem, and when I try to run the targets the build fails.

Comment: I never did.  I have, however, stopped using Linux, and my projects no longer use Ant as a build system.

Answer (score 5):

I was having this same problem with IntelliJ version 12.1.4. I solved it by putting jsch-0.1.50.jar into the default ant directory of IntelliJ (IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4\lib\ant\lib).

Comment: I did this too, but it didnt work right away. I needed to: 1. close all but one project if more than one are opened.  2. remove the jsch.jar and ant-jsch.jar from the Additional classpaths. 3. put the jsch.jar in the intellij ant lib directory (where ant-jsch.jar is at).  4. restart the IDE.

Comment: Same here. It's a pity because it's not THE way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

We can't reproduce the problem, `scp` is correctly recognized in the editor and works with just **jsch-0.1.45.jar** added to the **Additional Classpath**:

[image: scp works]

Please [submit a bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA) with an isolated test case and the steps to reproduce if you still have this problem.

Comment: How do you add `jsch` to the `Additional Classpath`?

Comment: Open the build file properties dialog and add the jar to the classpath. Details can be found in Help.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem for all additional jar by installing them in a user scope.

If you have an ant installation, run

```
ant -f fetch.xml -Ddest=user
```

A step by step can be found [here](https://datacadamia.com/ide/idea/ant)